# Syncing 2 phpMyAdmin Databases with different names

Tags: phpmyadmin

I run Kodi at home with a synced database. Running Kodi 18 it rights to a db called MyVideo108.  I want to run an older version of Kodi, Kodi 17 which writes to MyVideo107 db.

Is there a way to script a sync so that if an update is made to db MyVideo107 syncs to MyVideo108? and vica versa?